# regarding to Computer RAMs

Tags: byte, bit, ram

So I was reading on word size of a computer, in the book, it says "The main indication of the word size is how much memory the processor can address. A 32-bit processor is limited to 232 memory addresses, each of which usually holds one byte. Hence, 32-bit PCs and Macs are limited to a maximum of 4 gigabytes of electronic memory (RAM and ROM)."
My question would be , does that mean the limited RAM for 64-bit processor is 8 gigabytes??
I remember seen 16 gigabytes of RAM before

Comment: There are other limits in place. Current 64-bit processors won't go beyond 48 bits of physical RAM because that's all the bits that are wired out of the chip.

Comment: Macs use the same processors as PCs (in the past like 6 years or so, every mac had an 64bit processor)

Answer (score 1):

No 2^32 is 4GB
2^64 is 16 billion gigabytes ... much bigger

Comment: I.e. 16 billion gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that the limited RAM for a 64-bit processor is 4GB x 4GB, which is 16EB (ExaByte).